# MBRP(model based recursive partitioning) with R "glmertree" got error "subscript out of bounds, not all 'rhs' available"

Tags: r, partitioning, recursive-model

Originally I ran multilevel regression on to exam how social network properties (SNPs) (e.g. degree, centralities, group size, group centralizations ...) affect individual's productivity outcome.
Now I would like to see if the relationship between the predictors (SNPs) and outcome (productivity) is similar or different in the subgroups, or discover the hidden subgroups in the data population.

Using package glmertree, I keep encountering the same error:

```
Warning message in formula.Formula(ff, lhs = 1L, rhs = c(1L, 3L)):
“subscript out of bounds, not all 'rhs' available”
Error in attr(ff, "rhs")[[2L]]: subscript out of bounds
```

1. Is the error caused by some issues in my dataset? For example, very little factor variables? distribution of values in each variables?

Because I ran glmertree using the code and an example dataset from the supplemental materials of Fokkema, Edbrooke-Childs & Wolpert (2020) https://doi.org/10.1080/10503307.2020.1785037 and it works fine.

2. what is the basic requirement of glmertree? what kind of data it is suitable?
3. is there other better packages to achieve my goal of analysis? or other method rather than MBRP?

## What I did and results

data2 = Full dataset for analysis, its summary is:

```
'data.frame':   14181 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ prodgap_relat_node_avg: num  2.56 2.56 2.56 2.56 2.56 ...
 $ clust                 : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ deg                   : num  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ const                 : num  0.375 0.375 0.375 0.375 0.375 ...
 $ nd_bet_cen            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ nd_cl_cen             : num  0.485 0.485 0.485 0.485 0.485 ...
 $ nd_ei_cen             : num  0.0666 0.0666 0.0666 0.0666 0.0666 ...
 $ fileteamsize          : int  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ teamlevel             : Factor w/ 5 levels "crowd","dyadic",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
```

```
prodgap_relat_node_avg     clust             deg            const        
 Min.   :0.000126       Min.   :0.0000   Min.   : 1.00   Min.   :0.06806  
 1st Qu.:0.639601       1st Qu.:0.1028   1st Qu.:12.00   1st Qu.:0.06806  
 Median :1.109216       Median :0.1846   Median :40.00   Median :0.10130  
 Mean   :0.852597       Mean   :0.3802   Mean   :36.27   Mean   :0.15289  
 3rd Qu.:1.114702       3rd Qu.:0.6818   3rd Qu.:60.00   3rd Qu.:0.23183  
 Max.   :4.062727       Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :60.00   Max.   :1.00000  
   nd_bet_cen        nd_cl_cen         nd_ei_cen       fileteamsize 
 Min.   :0.00000   Min.   :0.01515   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :1.00  
 1st Qu.:0.00239   1st Qu.:0.53043   1st Qu.:0.1500   1st Qu.:2.00  
 Median :0.17501   Median :0.70523   Median :0.3510   Median :3.00  
 Mean   :0.26680   Mean   :0.72023   Mean   :0.2935   Mean   :3.41  
 3rd Qu.:0.54622   3rd Qu.:0.91266   3rd Qu.:0.4298   3rd Qu.:4.00  
 Max.   :0.54622   Max.   :0.91266   Max.   :0.4298   Max.   :9.00  
       teamlevel   
 crowd      :2733  
 dyadic     :3416  
 group      :2518  
 solo worker:3288  
 tradic     :2226
```

To simplify, I created a subdata containing 50 observations of data2, summary of data3:

```
'data.frame':   50 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ prodgap_relat_node_avg: num  2.56 2.56 2.56 2.56 2.56 ...
 $ clust                 : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ deg                   : num  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ const                 : num  0.375 0.375 0.375 0.375 0.375 ...
 $ nd_bet_cen            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ nd_cl_cen             : num  0.485 0.485 0.485 0.485 0.485 ...
 $ nd_ei_cen             : num  0.0666 0.0666 0.0666 0.0666 0.0666 ...
 $ fileteamsize          : int  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ teamlevel             : Factor w/ 5 levels "crowd","dyadic",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
```

```
prodgap_relat_node_avg     clust             deg            const        
 Min.   :0.0184         Min.   :0.1028   Min.   : 3.00   Min.   :0.06806  
 1st Qu.:0.4963         1st Qu.:0.1028   1st Qu.: 3.00   1st Qu.:0.06806  
 Median :1.1147         Median :0.2237   Median :31.00   Median :0.13111  
 Mean   :1.3344         Mean   :0.4362   Mean   :31.04   Mean   :0.19036  
 3rd Qu.:2.5566         3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:60.00   3rd Qu.:0.37485  
 Max.   :2.5566         Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :60.00   Max.   :0.37485  
   nd_bet_cen        nd_cl_cen        nd_ei_cen        fileteamsize
 Min.   :0.00000   Min.   :0.4848   Min.   :0.06663   Min.   :4    
 1st Qu.:0.00000   1st Qu.:0.4848   1st Qu.:0.06663   1st Qu.:4    
 Median :0.08885   Median :0.6398   Median :0.27468   Median :4    
 Mean   :0.20450   Mean   :0.6758   Mean   :0.25596   Mean   :4    
 3rd Qu.:0.54622   3rd Qu.:0.9127   3rd Qu.:0.42977   3rd Qu.:4    
 Max.   :0.54622   Max.   :0.9127   Max.   :0.42977   Max.   :4    
       teamlevel 
 crowd      : 0  
 dyadic     : 0  
 group      :50  
 solo worker: 0  
 tradic     : 0
```

My R code:

```
install.packages("glmertree")
library("glmertree")
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
getwd()
data <- read.csv("/content/github.android_final.csv")

data1 <-  data[, c("prodgap_relat.byfile.email._mean.bynode.","clust","deg","const","nd_bet_cen","nd_cl_cen","nd_ei_cen","fileteamsize")]
names(data1) <-c("prodgap_relat_node_avg","clust","deg","const","nd_bet_cen","nd_cl_cen","nd_ei_cen","fileteamsize")

data2 <- data1 %>%
  mutate(teamlevel = case_when(
    fileteamsize == 1 ~ "solo worker",
    fileteamsize == 2 ~ "dyadic",
    fileteamsize == 3 ~ "tradic",
    fileteamsize %in% c(4, 5) ~ "group",
    fileteamsize >= 6 ~ "crowd"
  ))
data2$teamlevel <- as.factor(data2$teamlevel)

data3 <- head(data2,50)

tree1 <- lmertree(prodgap_relat_node_avg ~ clust + deg + const + nd_bet_cen + nd_cl_cen + nd_ei_cen + teamlevel , data = data3)
tree2 <- lmertree(prodgap_relat_node_avg ~ clust + deg + const , data = data3)
tree3 <- lmertree(prodgap_relat_node_avg ~ clust , data = data3)
```

Error I got no matter tree1,2,or 3:

```
Warning message in formula.Formula(ff, lhs = 1L, rhs = c(1L, 3L)):
“subscript out of bounds, not all 'rhs' available”
Error in attr(ff, "rhs")[[2L]]: subscript out of bounds
```

**Note: I tried the glmertree formula on data2 as well, same error as data3.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model formulas are not glmertree formulas, hence the error. As per e.g. the tutorial you refer to, a glmertree formula comprises three parts, separated by vertical bars (`|`):

response ~ node-specific predictors | global predictors | partitioning variables

A longer explanation of these model parts are described informally at the bottom of this post, and more extensively in https://doi.org/10.3758/s13428-017-0971-x and the package vignette https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=glmertree/vignettes/glmertree.pdf.

Your formulas appear to specify only the first part: response ~ node-specific predictors. This might not be what you intend.

You wrote about your prediction question:

> exam how social network properties (SNPs) (e.g. degree, centralities, group size, group centralizations ...) affect individual's productivity outcome. Now I would like to see if the relationship between the predictors (SNPs) and outcome (productivity) is similar or different in the subgroups, or discover the hidden subgroups in the data population.

Your code has:

```
tree1 <- lmertree(prodgap_relat_node_avg ~ clust + deg + const + nd_bet_cen + nd_cl_cen + nd_ei_cen + teamlevel , data = data3)
tree2 <- lmertree(prodgap_relat_node_avg ~ clust + deg + const , data = data3)
tree3 <- lmertree(prodgap_relat_node_avg ~ clust , data = data3)
```

These yield errors, because the global model part and partitioning variables seem to be missing or incorrectly specified.

It looks like `prodgap_relat_node_avg` is the response variable (an individual's productivity outcome), `clust` is an indicator for cluster, and `deg + const + nd_bet_cen + nd_cl_cen + nd_ei_cen + teamlevel` are a set of social network properties. Going by the description of your research question, you want to find subgroups for which the association between SNPs and the response is different. However, seven possible predictors is a bit much, glmertree is mostly useful if there is an effect of one specific predictor, maybe two, that is of interest (i.e., where you want to identify subgroups that differ in the effect of this predictor). Also, sometimes researchers are interested in finding intercept differences only, so they might only be interested in finding subgroups with different means. I am not completely sure what is the specific research question you want to address here.

There are many ways to turn the formulas you wrote into something that works with glmertree, but each will answer a different research question. I provide suggestions here, perhaps you can update your post with a more exact description of e.g. which are the predictor variables of interest, and which variables are possible subgroup descriptors (i.e., partitioning variables).

The following formula would fit a model that finds subgroups (described by variables `deg`, `const`, `nd_bet_cen`, `nd_cl_cen`, `nd_ei_cen` and/or `teamlevel`) with a different mean of `prodgap_relat_node_avg`, while accounting for correlations between observations with the same value of `clust`:

```
prodgap_relat_node_avg ~ 1 | clust | deg + const + nd_bet_cen + nd_cl_cen + nd_ei_cen + teamlevel
```

The following formula would fit a model that finds subgroups (described by variables `const`, `nd_bet_cen`, `nd_cl_cen`, `nd_ei_cen` and/or `teamlevel`) with a different intercept or slope of the regression of `prodgap_relat_node_avg` on `deg`, while accounting for correlations between observations with the same value of `clust`:

```
prodgap_relat_node_avg ~ deg | clust | const + nd_bet_cen + nd_cl_cen + nd_ei_cen + teamlevel
```

I am assuming `clust` is an identifier for the cluster that observations are part of, with respect to which a random intercept should be estimated.

### Model parts

- **node-specific predictors**: predictor variables that you expect to have a different effect (i.e., different parameters) between the subgroups that you want to find. E.g., this could be an effect of treatment (when you expect some subgroups benefit more/less from treatment than others; `response ~ treatment`), or time (when you expect some subgroups show greater/smaller increase or decrease over time than others; `response ~ time`), or only an effect of the intercept (when you expect some subgroups have higher/lower means on the response than others; `response ~ 1`).
- **global predictors**: predictor variables for which you believe the parameters are constant for the whole sample. These can be random and/or fixed effects (but you need to specify a random effect here, otherwise use of package **`glmertree`** does not make sense). A random intercept and/or slope is the most common case. Some examples:

  - `| subjectID |`, which is **`glmertree`** shorthand notation for `| (1|subjectID) |` would estimate a subject-specific random intercept, which has only one parameter: the variance of the random intercept, which will be estimated using *all* observations in the dataset. Similarly, `| centerID |` is shorthand notation for `| (1|centerID) |` and would estimate a treatment-center-specific random intercept with its variance estimated using all observations in the dataset.
  - One can additionally include random slopes, which would be specified, e.g., as `| time + (1+time|subjectID) |` so that there will be three random-effects parameters estimated, using all observations in the dataset: variances for random intercept and random slope of time, and the covariance between them. It is customary in mixed-effects models to also estimate a fixed effects of predictors for which a random effects is estimated, hence `time` is specified here as both a fixed-effects predictor and random-effects (`time|subjectID`) predictor.

    - The usual **`lme4`** specifications can be used for random and fixed effects in the `| global predictors |` part of the **`glmertree`** formulas. Thus, if you do not want the covariance between the random intercept and slope to be estimated, you can specify `| time + (1|subjectID) + (time|subjectID) |`
  - One may want to include a global fixed effect, for example if you are interested in subgroups that have different treatment effects, but you want to correct for the pre-treatment score for all individuals in the dataset in the same manner. Then the first two parts of the formula could look something like: `posttreatment_score ~ treatment | (1|subjectID) + pretreatment_score |`. A fixed effect of the pre-treatment score and a random intercept will now be estimated using all observations in the dataset.
- **partitioning variables**: these are the possible characteristics that distinguish the different subgroups to be found from each other. For example, if one is interested in discovering subgroups of children that develop academic skills differently over time, these may consist of age at baseline, SES at baseline, characteristics of their parents and home situation at baseline, indicators of academic, social or psychological functioning at baseline. Or if one is interested in subgroups of individuals with different productivity outcomes, these may be variables measuring features of the individual, or features of the environment they are working in.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works and the key is the understanding to the components of glmertree formula. A further question regarding this: 
"response ~ node-specific predictors | global predictors | partitioning variables" 
What is the definitions of or difference between node-specific predictors, global predictors , and partitioning variables ?? Is there any recommended references to read further?

Comment: @nill I hope the more extensive description of the model parts address your question. Otherwise, Fokkema et al. (2018) is the only additional reference I can provide (DOI added in the post; you already found Fokkema, Edbrooke-Childs & Wolpert). The possibilities are endless, which also makes it challenging to immediately understand all model components. Hope this helps!

Comment: Amazing, thanks so much for the details! I just realized you are the first author! Really appreciate the help :)